# Clang c-api total memory usage

Tags: c++, clang, llvm-clang, libclang

How to get total memory usage of clang c-api for a given translation unit?

There is [`clang_getCXTUResourceUsage`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX__TRANSLATION__UNIT.html#gaacd1a1e9d83aaeec6b800e701b3a53f5) but it returns memory usage broken into [entries](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX__TRANSLATION__UNIT.html#ga13810240df7c205de04daac58f956396) where each entry describes certain category.

**UPDATE1:**
[Documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/Index_8h_source.html#l01488) states the units of `CXTUResourceUsageEntry::amount` depends on `CXTUResourceUsageEntry::kind` and doesn't say how. 
So it isn't clear how to sum it up.

Comment: Is there a tag for clang api?

Comment: _"Is there a tag for clang api?"_ May be [tag:llvm-clang] works out as the better tag.

Comment: What is the problem with summing it up in a `for` loop?

Comment: @luk32 it isn't clear what is the unit of `CXTUResourceUsageEntry::amount`.